# How does saveOrUpdate compare data in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I am learning Hibernate (beginner here). I wanted to know how the saveOrUpdate method does a comparison of records in the table and data hold in object which is in transient state.

Example code snippet:

```
package com.crudoperations;


import org.hibernate.Session;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;


import com.beans.Student;


public class CRUDMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Configuration cfg = new Configuration();

    cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

    ServiceRegistryBuilder service = new ServiceRegistryBuilder();

    ServiceRegistry sRegitry = service.applySettings(cfg.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();

    SessionFactory sf = cfg.buildSessionFactory(sRegitry);


    Session session = sf.openSession();

    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();


    Student stud = new Student();

    stud.setId(101);

    stud.setSname("abc");

    stud.setEmail("abc@gmail.com");

    stud.setMarks(89);


    //      System.out.println("invoking save() method.");

    //      int pk = (Integer) session.save(stud);      

    //      System.out.println("PK:"+pk);


    System.out.println("invoking saveOrUpdate() method.");

    session.saveOrUpdate(stud);

    tx.commit();

}

};


package com.beans;


public class Student {

private int id;

private String sname;

private String email;

private int marks;


public Student() { }


public int getId() {

    return id;

}


public void setId(int id) {

    this.id = id;

}


public String getSname() {

    return sname;

}


public void setSname(String sname) {

    this.sname = sname;

}


public String getEmail() {

    return email;

}


public void setEmail(String email) {

    this.email = email;

}


public int getMarks() {

    return marks;

}


public void setMarks(int marks) {

    this.marks = marks;

}   

}
```

I have read that using saveOrUpdate() first selects the record from the  database and compares the selected data with data in stud object. If it matches no insertion happens but if it doesn't match then data in stud object is inserted. How does the comparison happen since we haven't overridden the equals method in Student pojo. Table contains data with:

```
id=101, name=abc, email=abc@gmail.com, marks=89
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`saveOrUpdate()` does not compare objects based on equality, it compares on the identifier (@Id column(s)).

From hibernate docs (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-makingpersistent):

> saveOrUpdate() does the following:
>
> if the object is already persistent in this session, do nothing
>
> if another object associated with the session has the same identifier, throw an exception
>
> if the object has no identifier property, save() it
>
> if the object's identifier has the value assigned to a newly instantiated object, save() it
>
> if the object is versioned by a  or , and the version property value is the same value assigned to a newly instantiated object, save() it
>
> otherwise update() the object

So to answer your question, `saveOrUpdate()` does NOT first fetch the entity from the database and compare.

Answer (score 0):

`SaveorUpdate()` works based on the identifier.

> How does hibernate detect which instances are old and which are new?

A range of options is available. Hibernate assumes that an instance is an unsaved transient instance if:

- The identifier property is null
- The Version or timestamp property (if it exists) is null
- The new instance of the same persistent class, created by hibernate internally, has the same identifier value as the given instance.
- You supply an unsaved-value in the mapping  document of class, and the value of identifier property matches.
- Entity data with the same identifier value isn't in the second level cache.